# Best Relational Database Diagrams

Tags: database, diagram, relational

I am looking for good-designed and real life relational database diagrams. Could you offer any book or other sources? I prefer books.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean with "*real-life relational database diagrams*", but any data structures that you need serialized in a **relational** (SQL) scheme, must first come from a class or class-like diagram. in order to create a **well-designed relational database structure** based on these classes, one must first submit it to a series of transformations, known as Normalization Degrees. This will help keep your database redundancy-free and organized. (except when redundancy is a business requirement defined by you).
PDF books:
http://cir.dcs.uni-pannon.hu/cikkek/Database_Normalization.pdf
http://www.cs.cityu.edu.hk/~helena/cs34622000B/Normalization.pdf

I hope this helps!